# SailsJS Triggers Update when Creating Object with Associations

Tags: javascript, socket.io, associations, sails.js, waterline

I am using Sails v0.10.5.

I have created three models with associations in between them. There is a `Candidate` model, an `Evaluator` model and a `Rating` model by which an evaluator rates a candidate. I am using Waterline associations to automatically keep track of the foreign keys from `Rating` to `Evaluator` and `Candidate`.

I am also using Blueprint to automagically take care of all the CRUD routing for these models.

Unfortunately, whenever I create a new candidate via Blueprint with a url such as `http://localhost:1337/rating/create?rating=4&comment=Great&evaluator=3&candidate=2` in addition to triggering the expected CREATE, sails is also going back and calling 2 UPDATE's during which the foreign keys to each of `Candidate` and `Evaluator` are being set.

This is causing problem on the front-end of my application as it receives an UPDATE event instead of a CREATE event, and doesn't have the necessary context to properly deal with the new data coming from the server.

Any suggestions for a way around this issue would be helpful!

Here are the Waterline models:

`/api/models/Candidate.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  schema: true,
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    status: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    role: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    ratings: {
      collection: 'rating',
      via: 'candidate'
    }
  }
};
```

`/api/models/Evaluator.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  schema: true,
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    title: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    role: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    ratings: {
      collection: 'rating',
      via: 'evaluator'
    }
  }
};
```

`/api/models/Rating.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  schema: true,
  attributes: {
    rating: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true
    },
    comment: {
      type: 'string',
      required: false
    },
    evaluator: {
      model: 'evaluator',
      required: true
    },
    candidate: {
      model: 'candidate',
      required: true
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `publishCreate` for the `Rating` model.  Most of the [code in the default `publishCreate` method](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/stable/lib/hooks/pubsub/index.js#L1212) is devoted to figuring out which associations to notify about the new model, and how to notify them; since this is precisely what you *don't* want, your method in `models/Rating.js` can be very simple:

```
publishCreate: function (values, req) {

  // Get all of the "watchers" of the Rating model
  var watchers = Rating.watchers();

  // Remove the socket responsible for the creation, if you don't want
  // it to get the "create" message too
  watchers = _.without(watchers, req.socket);

  // Send a message to the sockets with the "rating" event and the payload
  // expected for the "publishCreate" message
  sails.socket.emit(sockets, "rating", {
      verb: 'created',
      data: values,
      id: values[this.primaryKey]
  });

  // Subscribe all watchers to the new instance, if you're into that
  this.introduce(values[this.primaryKey]);

}
```

Note that `publishCreate` is a *class* method of the model, so it goes *outside* the `attributes` object.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem similar to this. You can create a filter in your update event to check and see if certain variables were updated, and if they were, call some function that affects your front end.